# Risk aversion and inter dependency in finance

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, modeling, models, game-theory

In almost all papers that I read in quantitative finance trying to model a situation where several financial agents interact the distribution of the individual risk aversion is considered as independent of anything else.

But in my mind this seems very restrictive because I can not stop thinking that in such a situation, some interdependency should appear between agents (because of the market situation, public information…) with an impact on their risk aversions.

I would like to know where my intuition is wrong please.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Some people distinguish between Riks Aversion and Risk Appetite. Risk Aversion is thought to be "in your genes" or determined by early upbriging and to be generally stable (a part of your psychological character). Risk Appetite is much more situational (as is food appetite, i.e. do I feel hungry right now?) and could be influenced by what you see in the media, what you see others do, etc. But presumably born gamblers will always be gamblers and cautious people will always be cautious, within some narrow range influenced by environment.

Comment: In addition to what @nbbo2 said, there are also influential macro-finance papers that allow for (endogenously) time-varying risk aversion. Most famously, the habit model from [Campbell and Cochrane (1999, JPE)](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/250059) where agents are more risk averse during recessions when their consumption comes dangerously close to their ``habit consumption'' with which they feel comfortable. Conversely, risk aversion is lower in booms which aligns with higher stock prices and low expected returns.